# Which is the correct answer?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

The bathroom floor is all wet. Who ______ a shower?
a) had
b) had had 
c) had been having 
d) has been having

Comment: There are several possibilities - both (a) and (d) fit the blank quite naturally, and if we allow a contemplative mood, (c) might as well, possibly even (b). As written, it's 'primarily opinion-based' which to pick. You might be able to narrow it down with further context.

Answer (score 1):

> a) "had"

if those are the only 4 options.

In American English, though, it would be more common to hear:

> "The bathroom floor is all wet. Who [just] **took** a shower?"

Answer (score 0):

Certainly any answer here is contingent on the overall context; however, if it were me, I'd shorten this sentence as follows: 'Who showered?'

Answer (score 0):

I'd say *Who has had a shower?* (British English)